# Mat-Toolbar Align Items (left, center and right)

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, material-design

I developed a toolbar but I can't align elements on the same line, left, center and right.

Does anyone know how I can align these elements?

I notice that the elements with the name Align left are aligned to the left, the align center aligned to the center and the align right aligned to the right.

Thanks

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ipxkfu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Code**

```
  <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>  
      <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm>
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>

      <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Align left</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Align left</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Align center</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Align center</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Align right</a>
        <a href="#" mat-button>Align right</a>
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```html
<div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md fxFlex fxLayout>
  <!-- The following menu items will be hidden on both SM and XS screen sizes -->
  <div fxFlex>
     <a href="#" mat-button>Align left</a>
     <a href="#" mat-button>Align left</a>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="center center">
     <a href="#" mat-button>Align center</a>
     <a href="#" mat-button>Align center</a>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="flex-end center">
     <a href="#" mat-button>Align right</a>
     <a href="#" mat-button>Align right</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, 
is exactly what I needed, thank you very much

Comment: @PaulTh.Yeaah super ! :D

Answer (score 16):

css. This expands to occupy max available space.

```
.flexExpand {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

in your template use flexExpand utility to separate the items

```
<mat-toolbar>
<mat-toolbar-row>
 <div >
      <a mat-button [routerLink]="'/accounts'"> Accounts </a>
      <a mat-button [routerLink]="'/create-account'"> Create Account </a>
    </div>
    <span class="flexExpand"></span>
    <div >
      <a mat-button [routerLink]="'/logout'"> Logout </a>
    </div>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```